# hibernate *sometimes* fails on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, hibernate

**EDIT: This is not a duplicate. The other question describes a consistent failure. My system can hibernate and resume** *sometimes,* **indicating that the basic config (kernel command line, etc) is correct.**

Most of the time `sudo pm-hibernate` hibernates my machine properly, and there are no problems on restore. I have a huge swap partition and there were no issues before upgrading from Ubuntu 12.04.

Now the command sometimes exits with `1` immediately and absolutely nothing happens. Or it hangs for ~10 minutes, also with no effect. From my  `pm-suspend.log`:

```
Fri Jun 17 19:13:16 MSK 2016: performing hibernate
sh: echo: I/O error
Fri Jun 17 19:20:32 MSK 2016: Awake.
Fri Jun 17 19:20:32 MSK 2016: Running hooks for thaw
```

The disk is new and healthy. Where does this I/O error happen, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Why don't you try to suspend the system by going on the power-button and selecting suspend or physically hit the power-button and suspend the system instead of using  `pm-hibernate` command it is easier and faster way to suspend/hibernate system.

Comment: @Creator Thanks, but I specifically need hibernate (not suspend) behaviour.

Comment: yeah there is no hibernate gui button defined on power panel you have to use command line hibernate option only.

Comment: `pm-hibernate` (which is just a symlink to `pm-action`) and friends write their log to `/var/log/pm-suspend.log`. After a failed hibernation attempt, can you please isolate the section of the last (attempted) suspend-resume cycle and submit it here? The output of `sudo dmesg | tail -n 50` might help too.

Comment: Updated the question with error from `pm-suspend.log`.